# Problem with Mocking Behaviour of Toast in Android

Tags: java, android, mockito

I am making a calculator in Android Studio where users enter grades for different courses and a Toast message appears based on the average of the grades.

```
if (sum / 5.0 >= 2.5 && gpaValues[2] >= 3.0 && ((gpaValues[0] >= 1.7 && gpaValues[3] >= 1.7) || (gpaValues[0] >= 1.7 && gpaValues[5] >= 1.7) || (gpaValues[3] >= 1.7 && gpaValues[5] >= 1.7)) && pass == true) {
    StyleableToast.makeText(requireContext(), "You have met the requirements for this POSt!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG, R.style.passtoast).show();
} else if (sum / 5.0 < 2.5) {
    StyleableToast.makeText(requireContext(), "Unfortunately, you do not qualify for this POSt. Your GPA for these courses (excluding A08) must be greater than 2.5.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, R.style.failtoast).show();
} else if (gpaValues[2] < 3.0) {
    StyleableToast.makeText(requireContext(), "You must have a grade of at least 73 in CSC A48", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, R.style.failtoast).show();
} else if (((gpaValues[0] < 1.7 && gpaValues[3] < 1.7) || (gpaValues[0] < 1.7 && gpaValues[5] < 1.7) || (gpaValues[3] < 1.7 && gpaValues[5] < 1.7))) {
    StyleableToast.makeText(requireContext(), "You must have a grade of at least 60 in two of CSC/MAT A67, MAT A22, MAT A37", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, R.style.failtoast).show();
} else if (pass == false) {
    StyleableToast.makeText(requireContext(), "You must have passed all courses required for this POSt.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, R.style.failtoast).show();
}`
```

I am trying to use Mockito to test this:

```
public void testMetRequirements() {
        InSweFragment fragment = new InSweFragment();

        mockContext = mock(Context.class);
        when(fragment.requireContext()).thenReturn(mockContext);

        when(mockA67Text.getText().toString()).thenReturn("90");
        when(mockA08Text.getText().toString()).thenReturn("85");
        when(mockA48Text.getText().toString()).thenReturn("90");
        when(mockA22Text.getText().toString()).thenReturn("80");
        when(mockA31Text.getText().toString()).thenReturn("85");
        when(mockA37Text.getText().toString()).thenReturn("75");

        fragment.calculateGrade(mockA67Text, mockA08Text, mockA48Text, mockA22Text, mockA31Text, mockA37Text);

        verify(mockToast).makeText(mockContext, "You have met the requirements for this POSt!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG, R.style.passtoast);
    }
```

But I am getting the following error: "Fragment InSweFragment{67216c33} (1eee741c-d48b-425f-b3bc-7ff1820e8fe5) not attached to a context." because of here: when(fragment.requireContext()).thenReturn(mockContext);

I tried checking if context is null but that didn't work.
I also tried putting a getFragmentContext in the InSweFragment but that gave the same issues. I am not sure what to do, if anyone can help me that would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a lot to go through here.  First-  mocking a context will almost never work.  A context must be properly initialized by the framework. If you find you need to mock one, your probably have an architecture problem.

Secondly-  is this a unit test or a UI test?  Those are separate things, and should be done separately.  If this is a unit test, it should not require a Context at all.  If it's a UI test, you shouldn't be mocking anything and should be driving the UI via robots sending touch data.  This seems to want to be a unit test, make it one.

Third-  you're badly mixing your UI and business logic, resulting in hard to test code.  Separate it.  Your validation function should be passed in values, not be reading directly from the views.  It should return an error condition, rather than displaying the value.  Doing it that way will make it easy to write unit tests for the business logic without needing to fake or mock any of the UI stuff.